# How to put google map API in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

I got my library from

> http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library

and followed the instructions in

> http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/

but i am receiving an error message

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: 8192

Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Googlemaps has a deprecated constructor

Filename: libraries/Googlemaps.php

Line Number: 16

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test_map\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 25
Function: library

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test_map\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Try with renaming

```
function Googlemaps($config = array())
{
    if (count($config) > 0)
    {
        $this->initialize($config);
    }
    log_message('debug', "Google Maps Class Initialized");
}
```

to

```
function __construct($config = array())
{
    if (count($config) > 0)
    {
        $this->initialize($config);
    }
    log_message('debug', "Google Maps Class Initialized");
}
```

If doesn't work, than library probably needs more code changes since it is code older than 2-3 years.

Comment: it is giving me an error on regarding variable $map

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of class with CI_Googlemaps and the name of constructor with __construct